# How to create border line when using flex in mobile navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am having trouble to insert border to each webpage in responsive navigation bar. Borders come under links, but i want them evenly spaced between each webpage. The example is shown on the picture. I always get borders directly around text or around whole container.

Image link: https://ibb.co/vXQhLhX

Like you see in image i dont want borders around text, but in between webpages so i would have evenly bordered boxes, like i sketched on image.

Html:

```
<nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="logotip/S-digital10.png"  height=140  align=left></a>
        </div>  
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="spletne_strani.html" class="kazalec"> Spletne strani</a></li>
            <li><a href="optimizacija.html"> Optimizacija </a></li>
            <li><a href="cenik.html"> Cenik </a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt </a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html"> Blog </a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is CSS, i haven't included javascript, which causes to menu to appear when clicked and smooth animation.

CSS:

```
nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:20vh;
  background-color:white
}
.logo{
  color:black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size:20px;
}
.nav-links{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-around;
 width:30%
}
.nav-links li{
  list-style:none;
}
.nav-links a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size:14;
}
.burger div{
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px; /* top right bot left*/
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}
.burger{
  display:none;
}
.kazalec { 
    color:rgb(1, 111, 155);
    font-size:18px;
 } 
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
  .nav-links{
    width:60%}
  }
@media screen and (max-width:1080px){
  body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }
  .nav-links{
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    background-color: gray;
    height:30vh;
    top:20vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    width:50%;
    transform: translateX(100%); 
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
  .nav-links li{
    opacity:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  .burger{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZCH.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I used display:block instead of display:flex.